# is there a way to populate an ontology from a dataframe using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, owl, ontology

I already developed an ontology and I would like to populate this existing ontology  from data frame in python. is it possible?

Comment: why should it not? iterate over the rows and columns of the dataframe and add triples (rdflib) or axioms (owlready2) to the existing ontology via using the corresponding API methods in Python.

Comment: I am a beginner. Could you give me an example for the code plz

Comment: No, I can't. You have a Pandas dataframe, how to iterate the rows of a dataframe should be explained in the Pandas docs. How to add RDF triples (via `rdflib` API) or OWL axioms (via `owlready2` API) is explained quite well in their corresponding documentation.

Comment: ok thanks my problem was with the owlready